# RegEx to extract a word from mail's body

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I need to extract a word from incoming mail's body.

I used a Regex after referring to sites but it is not giving any result nor it is throwing an error.

Example: Description: sample text

I want only the first word after the colon.

```
Dim reg1 As RegExp
Dim M1 As MatchCollection
Dim M As Match
Dim EAI As String

Set reg1 = New RegExp

With reg1
    .Pattern = "Description\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)\s*"
    .Global = False
End With

If reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then
    Set M1 = reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
    For Each M In M1            
        EAI = M.SubMatches(1)    
    Next        
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure no errors are popping up? Try `M.SubMatches(0)` and see if there is no `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your `Sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your pattern works well though it is better written as:

```
Description\s*:+\s*(\w+)
```

And it will match `Description`, then 0+ whitespaces, 1+ `:` symbols, again 0 or more whitespaces and then will *capture* into Group 1 one or more word characters (as letters, digits or `_` symbols).

Now, the Capture Group 1  value is stored in `M.SubMatches(0)`. Besides, you need not run `.Test()` because if there are no matches, you do not need to iterate over them. You actually want to get a single match.

Thus, just use

```
Set M1 = reg1.Execute(Item.body)
If M1.Count > 0 Then
   EAI = M1(0).SubMatches(0)
End If
```

Where `M1(0)`  is the first match and `.SubMatches(0)` is the text residing in the first group.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor that helped but in my case if i have multiple words after the colon, i need those as well not only submatches(0) i need others also.

Comment: Description: abc def **now it is returning only abc i want def also in a string variable.

Comment: Then replace the `\w+` with `.+`. `\w+` match 1 or more letters, digits and `_`. The `.+` will match *any* 1 or more characters other than line break characters.

Comment: when i replace "Email Address\s*:+\s*(\w+)" with "Email Address\s*:+\s*(\.+)" it is not returning anything. As you can see i want to fetch email address but instead it is fetching only first name. in abc@xyz.com it is returning only abc. can't i get the whole mail address?

Comment: Why did you escape the dot? A `\.` matches a literal dot. I said to use `.+`: `Description\s*:+\s*(.+)`. If you need to match a chunk of non-whitespace symbols - then replace `(\w+)` with `(\S+)`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor that helped exactly my scenario. Thanks a lot for your help!!